# Which set does this small bag of LEGO pieces belong to?

Tags: set-identification

[image]

I just received a box of LEGO bricks and have no idea what sets they make up. This packet was in there unopened and thought someone might know where they are from?

Comment: That's a very small bag with only common elements in it, I doubt anyone will be able to give a definite answer.

Comment: I agree but I don't have any other elements to add since the box of legos is a mix of all sorts of elements.

Comment: @Henrik Sounds like a challenge.

Answer (score 8):

[image]

All the pieces shown are used in **[Day 17](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4428-18#T=I)** of the **[2012 LEGO City Advent Calendar (4428)](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=4428-1#T=I)**.

It looks like you only have 10 out of the 14 pieces required to build the model, the other pieces must have either been removed at some point or were never included (which is unlikely).

Comment: Yes, I would agree that this bag must have come from an advent calendar set or something similar, as no normal set would have so few pieces in a sealed bag. Perhaps it is from a different advent though? There may have been a similar build...

Comment: @SlicksterTheBrickster The [Blue Panel 1 x 2 x 1 with Rounded Corners](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4865b&colorID=7&in=A) only exists in 17 sets. I can't find any other sets on that list that match the parts used.

Comment: Are you sure it's a 1 x 2 x 1 with rounded corners, and not the counterpart without rounded corners?

Comment: When I searched I used the Red Tile, Round 2 x 2 because I thought it would be the rarest of those pieces. It has been used in [54 sets](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4150&colorID=5&in=A), looking at those results I couldn't find any other matches either.

Comment: Also the [Blue Panel 1 x 2 x 1 (without rounded corners)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=4865&colorID=7&in=A) don't appear to match anything either.